Adding XYZ button to QGIS Manage Layers Toolbars
QGIS manage Layers toolbar offers a quick shortcut to the "data source manager". For instance, clicking on the "add raster layer" button brings me immediately to the proper tab of the Manager:

Likewise, I can reach the "vector layer" tab, the "WMS layer" tab, etc.
As you can notice in the first screenshot, I can quite easily remove buttons from this toolbar using settings|Customization:

However, I now wish to add a shortcut to the XYZ tiles tab (in green in the first screenshot). Can this be done, and how?
(QGIS 3.38 under Windows 11, but probably applies to all QGIS 3.x releases)

You could add it with this short Python command (in the QGIS's Python Console (Ctrl+Alt+P):
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar

iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'mLayerToolBar').addAction(iface.actionAddXyzLayer())

You could also add a Keyboard Shortcut for "Add-XYZ-Layer":


If you want to insert the Button in a specific position you can use the insertWidget-method. Here you have to provide the QAction before you want to insert the XYZ-Button (The index of the children list can be different in your case):
from qgis.utils import iface
PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar, QAction

action_before = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'mLayerToolBar').findChildren(QAction)[3]
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, 'mLayerToolBar').insertAction(action_before, iface.actionAddXyzLayer())

If you want to execute this script at the start of QGIS, you could, for example, use a startup.py script.

Thanks! It works indeed, but the button disappear at the next restart. Is there a way to make the addition permanent ? Bonus question, can I insert the new button in an arbitrary position (say position #2)?

I edited my answer accordingly

My, my. The wonders of QGIS never cease to amaze me... If you want to run your code in startup.py (the existence of which I just discovered, thanks !), you need to also import QAction, changing your second line to :       from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar, QAction
